# Count number of functions in an object

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to count number of functions and properties inside this JavaScript object:

```
var Obj = {

    prop1: 'Property1',

    fun1: function() {
        console.log('function 1');
    },
    fun2: function() {
        console.log('function 2');
    }
}
```

So for properties I shout get 1 and 2 for functions here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var fCount = 0,
    pCount = 0;

for ( var i in Obj ) {
    if ( Obj.hasOwnProperty(i) ) {
        if ( typeof Obj[i] === "function" ) {
            fCount++;
        } else {
            pCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
Object.properties_size = function(obj) {
  var size = 0, key;
  for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && !(obj[key] instanceof Function)) size++;
  }
  return size;
};

Object.functions_size = function(obj) {
  var size = 0, key;
  for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] instanceof Function) size++;
  }
  return size;
};

var prop_size = Object.properties_size(Obj);
var func_size = Object.functions_size(Obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, simple:

```
var numFunctions = 0;
for (var p in Obj)
{
    if (Obj.hasOwnProperty(p) && typeof Obj[p] === 'function')
    {
        numFunctions++;
    }
}
```

**N.B.** `prop1`, `fun1`, and `fun2` are *all* properties of `Obj`. Object property values in JavaScript can hold any value, not just strings. ([David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13100812/139010) correctly shows how to also get a non-function property count.)

Answer (score 0):

you could do it this way

```
var num = 0;
for ( var k in Obj ) {
    num += ( Obj[k] && Function == Obj[k].constructor );
}
```